# how to write nested if else statement on django template

Tags: django-templates

Below is the code.  how to write nested if else statement on django template?

```
{%ifequal ser_id  3%}
     <label for="inputMobile" id="field-label" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Subscriber Id:</label>
     {%else ifequal ser_id 5%}
              <label for="inputMobile" id="field-label" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Phone No:</label>
               {%else%}
               <label for="inputMobile" id="field-label" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Mobile No:</label>
    {%endif%}
     {%endifequal%}
```

Comment: if any one knows corrections please tell me..i am getting error:Invalid block tag on line 28: 'else', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can't mix `{% ifequal %}` and with `{% else %}`
But ou can do this :

```
{% if ser_id == 3 %}
  <label for="inputMobile" id="field-label" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Subscriber Id:</label>
{% elif ser_id == 5 %}
  <label for="inputMobile" id="field-label" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Phone No:</label>
{% else %}
  <label for="inputMobile" id="field-label" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Mobile No:</label>
{% endif %}
```